# Datatable adding blanks row in Table when Firebase Database is updated

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, datatables

I want to stop auto refresh data in firebase.
I don't want to refresh them automatically.
I m using dataTable to Shows data From Firebase Database.
But as Firebase database is updated the dataTable Shows Extra Blanks row as the Firebase dtabse is Updated.

I m also attached Screen Shorts below.
[Screen 1 Before Database Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOq2G.png)

[After Databse Update It will Shows balnks Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1DGS.png)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         table = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": -1,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button type='button' class='mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-color-text--white'>Delete User</button>"

            } ],
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                    ],
        } );

        $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
            var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
           firebase.database().ref().child('mobilereg/' +  data[1]).remove();
           firebase.database().ref().child('limited_acces_devices/' +data[1]).remove();
           firebase.database().ref().child('full_acces_devices/' + data[1]).remove();
                     window.location.reload();
        } );
     });

     var ref = firebase.database().ref("mobilereg/");
 var i=0;
   ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
     var arr = snapshot.val();
 var arr2 = Object.keys(arr);

   snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
         var value = childSnapshot.val();
         var key = arr2[i];

         var dataSet = [i+1, arr2[i],value.screen];
        table.rows.add([dataSet]).draw();
        i++;
     });
   }, function (error) {
      console.log("Error: " + error.code);
   });
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

To only load the data once, use `once()` instead of `on()`:

```
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
```

But realtime updates are one of the key benefits of using Firebase, so I'd recommend figuring out what the actual cause of the blank rows is instead of disabling the realtime updates.

One simple way to do that is to clear out the `table.rows` before adding new items to it (so right before `snapshot.forEach`).

A more efficient way is to listen for the various `child_` events, and then update the table for new child nodes, deleted child nodes, and changed child nodes.

Comment: it's Working.Thanks.